# Journey Builder for SF Campaign Children

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, campaign, campaign-member

So I've created multiple SF campaigns (recruitment fairs) that need to be separate for reporting purposes. I've also grouped them under a parent campaign (all recruitment fairs for a particular time period). I'd like to setup a journey in Marketing Cloud that puts all the children of that parent campaign on the journey as I add new campaigns to the parent. In other words, every time a new recruitment fair happens, I'll create the campaign, add the leads into that campaign and then add that campaign to the parent at which time MC should send them on the e-mail journey.

Can't figure out how to make this happen and hooking up Journey Builder to the parent campaign did nothing. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using synchronised Data Extensions, write a query to pull all camapaign members based on parent campaign Id and populate them in a data extension. Use this as the entry source for your journey .

If you don't have SDE setup, just create a report in salesforce  for all leads with parent campaign and then import that into marketing cloud. Use this as entry source .

Automate the import process using Automation studio and every time you create a new campaign with leads under a parent, they will get injected into the journey.